# Change xmlns value from endpointInterface

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm having a Java webservice which looks like:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "vas.WSIF")
    public class WSImpl implements WSIF {
}
```

and an endpointInterface:

```
@WebService ()
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
    public abstract interface WSIF {
}
```

My request have to be:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:vas="http://vas/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <vas:sayhello>
         <info>?</info>
      </vas:sayhello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I change xmlns:vas="http://vas/" in to another value like xmlns:vas="http://hellovas.com"?
I think it's just follow the package name right now.

```
<!--
 Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e. 
-->
<!--
 Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e. 
-->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://vas/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://vas/" name="WSImplService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://vas/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/API?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="register">
<part name="msisdn" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="packageCode" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="channel" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="info" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="registerResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:registerResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="unregister">
<part name="msisdn" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="packageCode" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="channel" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="info" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="unregisterResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:unregisterResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="packagelist">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="packagelistResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:packagelistResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="checkstatus">
<part name="msisdn" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="checkstatusResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:checkstatusResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="decryptAES128">
<part name="input" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="decryptAES128Response">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="WSIF">
<operation name="register" parameterOrder="msisdn packageCode username password channel info">
<input wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/registerRequest" message="tns:register"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/registerResponse" message="tns:registerResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="unregister" parameterOrder="msisdn packageCode username password channel info">
<input wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/unregisterRequest" message="tns:unregister"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/unregisterResponse" message="tns:unregisterResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="packagelist" parameterOrder="username password">
<input wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/packagelistRequest" message="tns:packagelist"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/packagelistResponse" message="tns:packagelistResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="checkstatus" parameterOrder="msisdn username password">
<input wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/checkstatusRequest" message="tns:checkstatus"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/checkstatusResponse" message="tns:checkstatusResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="decryptAES128">
<input wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/decryptAES128Request" message="tns:decryptAES128"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://vas/WSIF/decryptAES128Response" message="tns:decryptAES128Response"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="WSImplPortBinding" type="tns:WSIF">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
<operation name="register">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="unregister">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="packagelist">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="checkstatus">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="decryptAES128">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://vas/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="WSImplService">
<port name="WSImplPort" binding="tns:WSImplPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/API"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add  more detail I dont know what the package names are for example.I really dont understand what you are trying to do. It might be simpler to author a WSDL first and the use the top down approach if you need very fine control on the service.

Comment: Hi Namphibian, I updated the wsdl, I was named my package as "vas", I tried to change it but it keeps become like xmlns:vas="http: //mypackagename/"